# HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request in java HTTP post

Tags: java, http, post

I am trying to post xml data to API using HTTP post method with credentials but a getting HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request error .. Can anyone pl help me out ....

Here is my sample code:

```
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(new File("Data.xml")));

        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

        while((line=br.readLine())!= null){
            sb.append(line.trim());
            }
        System.out.println("xml:  "+sb);



        params=sb.toString();
        HttpPost request = new HttpPost("*****************url***************");
        String urlaparam=URLEncoder.encode("importFormatCode:1&data:"+params,"UTF-8");
        String userCredentials = "****:******";
        byte[] auth = Base64.encodeBase64(userCredentials.getBytes());

        StringEntity entity=new StringEntity(urlaparam);
        request.addHeader("Content-type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
        request.addHeader("Accept", "application/xml");
        request.addHeader("Accept-Language", "en-US,en;q=0.5");
        request.addHeader("Authorization", "Basic " + new String(auth));


        request.setEntity(entity);
        HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(request);    

       System.out.println(response.getStatusLine());
       System.out.println(request);
}
    catch(Exception e)
{
}
```

Comment: I think, your parameter format is wrong. The key-value separator should be "=", not ":". You can use `org.apache.http.client.utils.URLEncodedUtils.format(...)` to encode your parameters.

Comment: can u pl explain briefly abt encoding

Comment: See http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#h-17.13.4.1

Answer (score 1):

First of all, your form parameters are not encoded correctly. You are using colon (`:`) to separate keys from their values, but instead, the equal sign (`=`) must be used:

- Wrong: `"importFormatCode:1&data:" + params`
- Correct: `"importFormatCode=1&data=" + params`

(See also [W3C.org - Forms in HTML Documents - application/x-www-form-urlencoded](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#h-17.13.4.1))

Apart from that, you must not URL-encode the entire string but only the keys and the values. Otherwise you'll also encode the separator characters `=` and `&`!

The easiest way is to use the existing utility class `org.apache.http.client.utils.URLEncodedUtils` (assuming that you're using [Apache HTTP Components](http://hc.apache.org/)):

```
String xmlData = // your xml data from somewhere

List<NameValuePair> params = Arrays.asList(
    new BasicNameValuePair("importFormatCode", "1"),
    new BasicNameValuePair("data", xmlData)
);
String body = URLEncodedUtils.format(params, encoding); // use encoding of request

StringEntity entity = new StringEntity(body);
// rest of your code
```

Comment: its fine .. thanks for your valuable reply  but pl tell me more about encoding that you have done ...string body = URLEncodedUtils.format(params, encoding);

Comment: @user3698939 What do you mean? I'm just calling the method of the utility class.

Comment: @user3698939 If you are interested in the encoding itself, please have a look at the W3C link I've posted.

Comment: Are you sure, the request is `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`? Usually, data like XML is NOT sent via HTTP that way.

Comment: Then you should better check the server API documentation; maybe something else is wrong (XML syntax, ...). Also inspect the error message that might come together with the error response. And do some tests using a REST-Client (e.g. Browser Plugin) to ensure the API works as expected.